# Android to remain logged in with cookies for fetching json data

Tags: java, android, json, cookies

This has been asked in different ways so far, but I am unable to find a solution to this particular issue.

**Short Version:**
I am seeking a way to fetch json from a URL that requires authentication. And rather than authenticating every time, I want it to store the received cookies so that it doesn't have to re-login, and on subsequent connections remain logged in.

**Long version:**
Basically, I want the app to store the user's username and password (as internal private strings with shared preferences). Then after that, it would call a login url to authenticate and remain logged in(get the cookies). Once this is done, I want the program to fetch json data from different urls (that require a user to be logged in via cookies for example). I want this to remain in place even after the app is paused or destroyed.
It can be considered as an idea similar to a chrome plugin that can simply fetch data from a website once its logged in.

I reckon the solution to this would be useful for many developers who are new to android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to not leave the question unanswered and explain how I solved the problem, here is my answer.

I resorted to use the [Loopj Android Async Http Client library](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/), which is being used by major apps like Instagram and Pinterest.

Keeping the cookies persistent is pretty simple this way. All you need is:

```java
AsyncHttpClient myClient = new AsyncHttpClient(); // a client instance

PersistentCookieStore myCookieStore = new PersistentCookieStore(this);
myClient.setCookieStore(myCookieStore); // setting the cookie store
```

Answer (score 0):

try this it stores username pass and session into shared pref

```
   app_preferences =    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    userid=app_preferences.getLong("userid",0);
    username=app_preferences.getString("username", "");

    password=app_preferences.getString("password", "");


    session=app_preferences.getString("session", "");





class task extends AsyncTask<String, integer, Boolean>{
    //httpreqclass htrq= new httpreqclass();

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        showProgressDialog();
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        String usr=params[0];
        String p=params[1];
        String data[]=new String[2];
    String ur=  "http://192.168.1.45/Android.asmx/Login";

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    data=   postData(usr,p,ur);

    boolean sucess=false;
    try {
        JSONObject jso = new JSONObject(data[0]);
        sucess =jso.getBoolean("isSucceeded");
        if (sucess) {
              SharedPreferences.Editor editor = app_preferences.edit();

            JSONObject jsr=  jso.getJSONObject("result");
            Long a= jsr.getLong("Id");
            editor.putLong("userid", a);
                editor.putString("username", usr);
                editor.putString("password", p);
                editor.putString("session", data[1]);

             editor.commit(); // Very important

        }

    }catch (Exception e){

    }

        return sucess;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    here put code what you want to do next


    }



}

public String[] postData(String u, String p,String url) {
    String asp = null,data = null;
    String[] rtrn=new String[2];

    //Log.e("i entrd here", "");


    try {
     HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(getHttpParams());
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost();
           HttpResponse response;
           List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();                
           params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("EmailId", u));
           params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("PassWord", p));                    
           UrlEncodedFormEntity ent = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params,HTTP.UTF_8);

    httppost.setEntity(ent);
            response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            Header[] headers;
         headers = response.getHeaders("Set-Cookie");
            //Header atha= respone.getFirstHeader("PHPSESSID");
             List<Cookie> cookies = ((AbstractHttpClient) httpclient).getCookieStore().getCookies();

             if (cookies.isEmpty()) {
                Log.d("TAG","no cookies received");
             } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < cookies.size(); i++) {

                    if(cookies.get(i).getName().contentEquals("ASP.NET_SessionId")) {
                     asp = cookies.get(i).getValue();
                   }
                }
                Log.e("this is the cookiee", asp);
                }  





               HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream is = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        String line = null;
                       while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            sb.append(line + "\n");
                        }
                      is.close();
                      Log.e("", sb.toString());
                      rtrn[0]=sb.toString();
                      rtrn[1]=asp;


        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    return rtrn;

 }



private HttpParams getHttpParams() {

        HttpParams htpp = new BasicHttpParams();

        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(htpp, 3000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(htpp, 5000);

        return htpp;
    }
```

you can refer the code and make the application as per your logic

and note when the next time onwards when you send a request to the server do not forget to add the session/cookie in the header

Comment: First I should say, thanks a lot for the time you spent writing the code.
Secondly, I am unable to run the code as there are few problems. for instance, I cannot find httpreqclass, pDlg, fetchdata, showProgressDialog ...
And third, is there any sort of walkthrough (or maybe a final method that uses the structure above). It may be useful putting a working version on github for everyone (or I can do it myself in the end, as I think this is useful for many people).
Thanks again

Comment: sry fr that ... i ll put it at git hub nd add here thnks

Comment: hi i have edited the code don't forget to change the url and parameters to corresponding 1 s that you have access to

Comment: Ok I have tried to get this to work, but I am still unable to get it to work.

Let me explain what the problem is. I have modified your code to set the cookies received in cookiemanager. Now I want to make a new connection and send the cookies along, however I dont know how to send the cookies on the secondary connection. would appreciate some help.

Comment: its better you use HttpURLConnection to use cookie manager but that update is only available from android 2.3 + for httpurlconnection it depends on what platform you want to use it     
 String addCookie = con.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie");
                    if (addCookie!=null) {
                cookieManager.getInstance().setCookie(url, addCookie);
            }